# Using PostAsync method from HttpClient Class with an API key in C#

Tags: c#, curl, httprequest

I would like to write the equivalent of this curl script in C#. My curl script is the following:

```
curl -X POST \
https://example.com/login \
-H 'api-key: 11111111' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{
"username": "myemail@hotmail.com,
"password": "mypassword"
}'
```

The corresponding C# code I have wrote is the following:

```
async static void PostRequest()
{
    string url="example.com/login"
    var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "myemail@hotmail.com"));
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "mypassword"));
    HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
    // where do I put my api key?
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, q))
        {
            using (HttpContent content =response.Content)
            {
                string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();              
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how do I include the Api Key to my request?

Comment: You don't want to create a new `HttpClient` for each request. Create it as a Singleton,  use `DefaultRequestHeaders` for headers that are common to all requests, then set request-specific headers on an `HttpRequestMessage` and pass that into the `HttpClient.SendAsync()` method.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For the Api you are calling, it appears as though the key is in the headers.
So use:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", "11111111");
```

Comment: it needs to go to the header